# Efficient Data Structure for "Model Number" Sub string Searching

Tags: java, search, substring

We have a problem where we want to do substring searching on a large number [1MM - 10MM] of strings ("model numbers") quickly identifying any "model number" that contains the given substring.  Model numbers are short strings such as:

1. ABB1924DEW
2. WTW9400PDQB
3. GLEW1874

The goal is simple, given a substring, quickly find all the model numbers match the substring.  For example (on the universe of above model numbers), if we searched on the string "EW" the function would return GLEW1874 and ABB1924DEW (because both contained the substring EW within them).

The data structure also needs to be able to support quick searches for model numbers that start with a given substring and/or end with a given substring.  For example, we need to be able to quicly do searchs like WTW...B (which would match WTW9400PDQB because it starts with WTW and ends with B)

What I am looking for is an in memory data structure that does that does these searches very efficiently.  Ideally, there would also be a nice (simple) implementation in Java already done somewhere that we could use.  Simple (and fast) is better than uber complicated and slightly faster.  The naive algorithm (just loop over all part numbers doing a substring search on each) is too slow for our purposes, we are looking for something much faster (prepossessing ok)

So, what is the textbook data structure/algorithm for this problem?

Comment: yeah it is very frustrating when you take your time to help ppl and they dont even bother to up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). I don't know of a library in Java to recommend so you might have to implement one yourself